# Image manipulation and character recognition in C?

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition, omr

I am inquiring about processing an image in C where I would like to scan an image for information, and then later use said info in my program. The image would take  the format of a class timetable (jpeg or png file) and I would need to extract some basic parts.

Here is an example file:

[image]

I need to (ideally) extract:

- The class names (CIS*3250*0102) etc.
- The day of the class
- The starting time of the class

My question is, what is the best way to go about doing this? I have done some research and found opencv and some other computer vision libraries, but they do not have direct documentation for C, and if they do I could not find it. If someone could link me to a library that would allow me to extract this information, and some documentation for implementing in C, that would be great!

If anyone has any tips on how to use said software I would appreciate that as well, but I am confident that I would be able to figure it out given the right resources. Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This may be too broad of a question for Stackoverflow.  Computer vision and image recognition are very, very broad and deep topics.  If you could live long enough, you can easily spend multiple academic careers doing work in the field.

Comment: Have you researched into Tesseract-OCR? It's an open-source library used for image-text recognition.

Comment: @Miket25 I actually did take a quick look, but sort of glossed over it. I will look into this with more detail now! Thanks.